# googleapiclient.errors.unknownapinameorversion name: sheets version: v4

Tags: python, google-sheets, error-handling, replit

So, i dont know what the problem is the code was working correct on local but when i hosted it on replit it gave me a error

```
googleapiclient.errors.unknownapinameorversion name: sheets version: v4
```

I tried fixing it by reinstalling the modules still it gave me the same error

```
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
```